# Classical potential for Yukawa interaction between scalars

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Let's consider that we have a complex scalar field $\varphi$ and a real scalar field $\chi$ which interact via the coupling,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{\rm int.} = -y\chi\varphi^\dagger\varphi
.
\end{equation}
The mass dimension of the Yukawa coupling $y$ is clearly $[y] = 1$. Now, I expect that the classical potential $V(r)$ is given by the Yukawa potential,
\begin{equation}
V(r) \propto \frac{y^2}{r}e^{-m_\chi r}
.
\end{equation}
The above proportionality has mass dimension 3 as opposed to the expected $[V] = 1$. What are the missing factors?

My first guess is that I should take $y\to y/m_\chi$, but this doesn't work well in the limit that $m_\chi \to 0$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is a second mass scale in the problem, *M* the mass of *φ*; you could stick it behind a now dimensionless coupling *g=y/M*.